# Storing mousemove event argument in global variable may cause performance problems?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I'm storing mousemove event arguments in variable, can it cause performance problems?

```
window.document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    window.mouse = e;
});
```

Comment: Nope, you're good in terms of performance. But I'd name it something way less collidable than "mouse" and stick it on a global application specific object, not directly onto the window object. window.MyApplicationsNamespace.lastMouseMoveEvent = e;

Comment: @JosephLennox thanks, i'll consider your advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any reason it would. You are making a function call and assigning a value to a variable every time the mouse moves, but those are pretty cheap to do in any circumstances I can think of. If you are seeing performance issues you can use the performance tools built in to most browsers to determine where your issues are occurring.

Comment: Thanks MichaelSmith for answer